# How do you do Automatic Select clauses if you dont have a WHERE statement?

Tags: petapoco

In the documentation it says you can decorate the POCO with the table name and primary key column so you dont have to specify the SELECT * FROM TABLENAME an can just use WHERE...

How do you use this feature if you dont have a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 3):

Just use an empty string.

```
var data = db.Fetch<User>("");
```